# How to instantiate uwp Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, media-player, uwp

I am trying to devlop a small example where I would use MediaCapture and MediaPlayer classes in universal windows app in order to record and play a short recording.

The following call to a constructor displays that lovely message in Visual Studio saying that there is no constructor which takes 0 arguments. The code doesn't compile therefore.

```
//using Windows.Media.Playback;
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
```

Msdn clearly states that there is such a constructor on [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.mediaplayer.aspx). On the other hand it states as well that

> [Some information relates to pre-released product which may be substantially modified before it's commercially released. Microsoft makes no warranties, express or implied, with respect to the information provided here.]

**Is it the case here that it has changed? Is it me being dumb? How can I find out?**

Comment: it says, Universal, introduced version 10.0.10240.0. which version do you have? although i don't think that might be the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on your Version. Before version 10.0.14393 you had to create background task for your player app. Instance has to be obtained thus:

```
MediaPlayer player = BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current;
```

But after anniversary update you don't need background task. You just can get new instance of player thus:

```
private MediaPlayer CurrentPlayer
   {
      get
      {
         if (_mediaPlayer != null) return _mediaPlayer;
         _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer {AutoPlay = false, AudioCategory = MediaPlayerAudioCategory.Media};
         return _mediaPlayer;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [MediaElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/media-playback#create-a-media-player) control in `uwp`.

Answer (score 1):

the MediaElement should work, just tried it in my Visual Studio

```
MediaElement ml = new MediaElement();
```

Comment: I agree that one could use MediaElement, but there are those who would be interesting in using Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer instead. Documentation make it seem like this class can be instantiated with 0 arguments, but the compiler disagrees.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 documentations that can help:

1. [As it says in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_6):

> MediaPlayer is different from a MediaElement in that it is not a control that can be added directly to the user interface (UI) of an application. To display media loaded using MediaPlayer, a VideoDrawing or DrawingContext must be used.

So you should use it inside a drawing (See [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969812(v=vs.110).aspx)).

2. The other says [it requires at least Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.mediaplayer).

Answer (score 0):

> Media player can be instantiate as below:
>
> private void LoadEmbeddedAppFile() {
>       MediaElement mediaPlayer = new MediaElement();
>       mediaPlayer.RealTimePlayback = true;
>
> }
>
> //Or you can use simple control from add on designer page..
>
> //Than you can define any video file to its source as below...
>
> private void LoadEmbeddedAppFile() {
>       try
>       {
>           Uri pathUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Videos/video1.mp4");
>           mediaPlayer.Source = pathUri;
>       }
>       catch (Exception ex)
>       {
>           if (ex is FormatException)
>           {
>               // handle exception. 
>               // For example: Log error or notify user problem with file
>           }
>       } }

Answer (score 0):

Just hit the same problem in my own project. If you cant instantiate MediaPlayer with 0 arguments you very likely have to change the target version of windows. This simplification of the audio playback has been introduced with the Anniversary Update so to use it, change the target to it.

In Visual Studio (2015):

1. Right click your Project
2. Choose `Properties`
3. `Application`tab
4. `Targeting` area
5. Set `Target version` & `Min version` to at least `Windows 10 Anniversary Edition`

[Screenshot - Visual Studio 2015 - Target version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYE8J.png)

Hope that helps everyone hitting the same problem =)

Answer (score -1):

```
//Media player can be instantiate as below:

private void LoadEmbeddedAppFile()
{
    MediaElement mediaPlayer = new MediaElement();
    mediaPlayer.RealTimePlayback = true;

}



//Or you can use simple control from add on designer page..

//<MediaElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" 
//Source="Videos/video1.mp4" 
//Width="400" 
//AutoPlay="False"
//AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"/>



//Than you can define any video file to its source as below...

private void LoadEmbeddedAppFile()
{
    try
    {
        Uri pathUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Videos/video1.mp4");
        mediaPlayer.Source = pathUri;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex is FormatException)
        {
            // handle exception. 
            // For example: Log error or notify user problem with file
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This just shows how to use MediaElement and not Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer.